# 'Novel' package

Tags: packages, package-writing

As an author writing in a LaTex environment, using the `novel`
package currently included in MacTex, I now understand that the package author (?) has withdrawn the package on the 7th May. However, the novel
package currently still appears in downloads of MacTex.
The package 
appears to be working normally for typesetting novels. So, my question
is two-fold:

1. whether it is safe to continue using the `novel`
   package, or
2. has someone else picked up the development/maintenance
   of this package. The package author has removed the stub from Github
   and has written on here there will be no further development or
   maintenance of the package.

Many thanks, Ben

Comment: Oh sorry, were you actually quoting someone else? I didn't notice that Ben in the text were different to your username.

Comment: *[As of 07-June-2017, this pack­age is no longer main­tained by its orig­i­nal cre­ator. It is “up for adop­tion”, if any­one is in­ter­ested. Prospec­tive adopters should note that the NovelDeco.otf font serves an es­sen­tial pur­pose for cer­tain func­tions, al­though it is not needed for gen­eral us­age.](http://ctan.org/pkg/novel)*

Comment: Torbjørn T: My fault I used my pseudonym by mistake

Comment: There are a lot of packages/classes that are inactive but are still available for use. It just means that there won't be any bug fixes or new features. They only tend to drop off the distributions if it turns out there's a problem with the licence or if they've been withdrawn because they're obsolete (and replaced with another package), which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: I see no particular problem with `novel.cls`, apart from it being “orphaned”. The license notes are in place and it seems to comply with the free software standards. So I don't think it risks to be removed from TeX Live.

Comment: there was an "official" announcement on june 9, to the effect that maintenance by the original author has been discontinued, and the package is "up for adoption".  however, that won't result in its removal from either ctan or tex live, since the license remains in place.

Comment: The package is not discontinued. Still available and very much alive. However, the original creator is getting old, and would like a someone else to pick up maintenance in the future. The "official" announcement on CTAN has been modified to clarify this. In fact, the package was updated after the June 9 announcement.

Answer (score 11):

A better answer than I wrote earlier (with an obsolete username):

I (the original creator of this package) reviewed things, and discovered a minor bug in the documentation, and a major bug in how the code handles text tracking. Both have been fixed.

Minor doc bug: Correct command is `\SetHeadFootStyle` not `\SetHeadStyle`.

The text tracking bug will affect many users, as it is part of defaults. Apparently it was triggered by recent changes to either fontspec or microtype. The fix is expected to be permanent, even if there are other changes to those packages. Users who encountered the bug may have gotten an obscure halt message involving MT@res@a. The fix involved replacing `\textls` with `\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=number}` in the code.

EDIT: Version 1.38 (current version as I write this) has been successfully used to create a novel, and also (with GIMP) its cover art. The book was automatically reviewed for compliance and accepted on first attempt by a major American P.O.D. service. It is now in print. Almost all of the layout uses the package defaults, so that the Preamble is absurdly simple. My point: The "novel" document class really works.

ANOTHER EDIT: I have also revived the GitHub page:
https://github.com/RobtAll/novel

Comment: Thank you for this document class. Especially love the FAQ in the [example document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/latex/novel/doc/novel.pdf). :-) It appears that people are leaving comments on the [CTAN page](https://ctan.org/pkg/novel) because it was removed from GitHub (the link referred to in an earlier version of the documentation no longer works). It appears that CTAN is really not a good place to leave the official version of a package these days (sadly), e.g. as “documentation” it links to just the first HTML file instead of all of them (and the rest are hard to find).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks for pointing that out. Maybe I will re-establish a GitHub account for this (later...). Now that I have a real novel out, I may re-write the html docs for better internal navigation.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The GitHub account is restored. You can view each page of the HTML documentation (formatted, with images) by pasting its GitHub URL into https://htmlpreview.github.io but you can only do it one page at a time, as they do not cross-link.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR CTAN is the ***only*** place worth putting the official version of the package, whether maintained or not. The use of CTAN to access documentation is not its primary purpose or use. (That said, if the link could point to something better, please let the CTAN maintainers know.) Its primary purpose is what it says on the tin: it is an archive. It is the persistent source of contributions to TeX. It is also, of course, the basis for both MikTeX and TeX Live. It it is not on CTAN, it doesn't exist for 99.9999999999999999999% of users. (Conservative estimate.)

Comment: @cfr I don't disagree on any of the facts: CTAN is good as an archive and a way to get your package into common distributions. It is not good as a place for users to follow development, to look at the source or even the documentation, to leave comments to the author, to volunteer for involvement, to look at earlier versions or history, etc. In short it's not great as the “source of truth” about something, which is what I meant by “official”. All this suggests one should do one's development/issue-tracking/user-interaction somewhere else, and just dump to CTAN whatever one want users to use.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR We're talking about an unsupported, unmaintained package. There is no author to interact with - the author has retired. There is no development - unless it gets adopted. For all of that, the status on CTAN is key, at least if the package is LPPL licensed. Generally, CTAN is fine for documentation because, in most cases, a PDF is the standard. But mostly documentation is available locally. That's how the system works. It is also pretty OK for looking at source and much less off-putting than somewhere like GitHub.

Comment: @cfr Look at the “Com­mu­nity Com­ments” at the bottom of https://www.ctan.org/pkg/novel, where users have tried to contact the author. Would you agree that CTAN is not a good place for such interaction? That was my main point (and the author seems to have agreed and reinstated the Github project). We can discuss more in the chat room instead of here and generating notifications for the author who probably has novels to write :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The package is, in fact, currently maintained. I am its author, and I maintain it. However, I am hoping that someone will take it over (at some future point). As cfr noted, CTAN is the official location, not GitHub. I did see the community comments on CTAN, which motivated me to continue maintenance. Also contacted a commenter by e-mail (got no reply). The only reason for using GitHub is to possibly post experimental code or additional non-TeX materials, not the official package. My e-mail is at the top of the novel.cls file.

Comment: @RobtAll I'm not the one who called it unmaintained. Again, thanks for the package, and may your novels have great success. (Perhaps “official” wasn't the best word for what I intended. I intended whatever you meant by the “that” and “this” in “Thanks for pointing that out. Maybe I will re-establish a GitHub account for this”.)